# Como simplificar una consulta

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estimadxs, buen día, quiero saber si se puede simplificar un `UPDATE` a varios campos de una tabla.
Tengo esta tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE #tabla_diseno2023v1(
    NominalR_1 FLOAT NULL, 
    DetalleR_1 NVARCHAR(150) NULL,
    NominalR_2 FLOAT NULL, 
    DetalleR_2 NVARCHAR(150) NULL,
    NominalR_3 FLOAT NULL, 
    DetalleR_3 NVARCHAR(150) NULL,
    NominalR_4 FLOAT NULL, 
    DetalleR_4 NVARCHAR(150) NULL,
    NominalR_5 FLOAT NULL,
    DetalleR_5 NVARCHAR(150) NULL
)
```

Y para hacer el `UPDATE`, hago lo siguiente:

```
UPDATE #tabla_diseno2023v1
SET NominalR_1 = (SELECT P330_VNominal FROM PlanSQL330 WHERE (PLAN_Nro = 1234) AND (P330_premio = 1)),
    DetalleR_1 = (SELECT P330_Detalle FROM PlanSQL330 WHERE (PLAN_Nro = 1234) AND (P330_premio = 1)), 
    NominalR_2 = (SELECT P330_VNominal FROM PlanSQL330 WHERE (PLAN_Nro = 1234) AND (P330_premio = 2)),
    DetalleR_2 = (SELECT P330_Detalle FROM PlanSQL330 WHERE (PLAN_Nro = 1234) AND (P330_premio = 2)),
    NominalR_3 = (SELECT P330_VNominal FROM PlanSQL330 WHERE (PLAN_Nro = 1234) AND (P330_premio = 3)), 
    DetalleR_3 = (SELECT P330_Detalle FROM PlanSQL330 WHERE (PLAN_Nro = 1234) AND (P330_premio = 3)), 
    NominalR_4 = (SELECT P330_VNominal FROM PlanSQL330 WHERE (PLAN_Nro = 1234) AND (P330_premio = 4)), 
    DetalleR_4 = (SELECT P330_Detalle FROM PlanSQL330 WHERE (PLAN_Nro = 1234) AND (P330_premio = 4)),
    NominalR_5 = (SELECT P330_VNominal FROM PlanSQL330 WHERE (PLAN_Nro = 1234) AND (P330_premio = 5)), 
    DetalleR_5 = (SELECT P330_Detalle FROM PlanSQL330 WHERE (PLAN_Nro = 1234) AND (P330_premio = 5))
```

¿Se puede simplificar de alguna forma con un `CASE` u otra cosa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usar subconsultas para un `UPDATE` es una operación costosa. Lo ideal es consultar la tabla `PlanSQL330` solo una vez y pivotear las filas para obtener todas las columnas. Esto se puede hacer con agregados condicionales.

```
SELECT  MAX(CASE WHEN P330_premio = 1 THEN P330_VNominal END) AS NominalR_1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN P330_premio = 1 THEN P330_Detalle  END) AS DetalleR_1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN P330_premio = 2 THEN P330_VNominal END) AS NominalR_2,
        MAX(CASE WHEN P330_premio = 2 THEN P330_Detalle  END) AS DetalleR_2,
        MAX(CASE WHEN P330_premio = 3 THEN P330_VNominal END) AS NominalR_3,
        MAX(CASE WHEN P330_premio = 3 THEN P330_Detalle  END) AS DetalleR_3,
        MAX(CASE WHEN P330_premio = 4 THEN P330_VNominal END) AS NominalR_4,
        MAX(CASE WHEN P330_premio = 4 THEN P330_Detalle  END) AS DetalleR_4,
        MAX(CASE WHEN P330_premio = 5 THEN P330_VNominal END) AS NominalR_5,
        MAX(CASE WHEN P330_premio = 5 THEN P330_Detalle  END) AS DetalleR_5
FROM PlanSQL330 
WHERE PLAN_Nro = 1234 
AND   P330_premio IN( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

Ahora sí, esto lo puedes usar en una tabla derivada (subconsulta) o en un CTE que me parece más organizado.

```
WITH ctePlanSQL330_Pivot AS(
    SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN P330_premio = 1 THEN P330_VNominal END) AS NominalR_1,
           MAX(CASE WHEN P330_premio = 1 THEN P330_Detalle  END) AS DetalleR_1,
           MAX(CASE WHEN P330_premio = 2 THEN P330_VNominal END) AS NominalR_2,
           MAX(CASE WHEN P330_premio = 2 THEN P330_Detalle  END) AS DetalleR_2,
           MAX(CASE WHEN P330_premio = 3 THEN P330_VNominal END) AS NominalR_3,
           MAX(CASE WHEN P330_premio = 3 THEN P330_Detalle  END) AS DetalleR_3,
           MAX(CASE WHEN P330_premio = 4 THEN P330_VNominal END) AS NominalR_4,
           MAX(CASE WHEN P330_premio = 4 THEN P330_Detalle  END) AS DetalleR_4,
           MAX(CASE WHEN P330_premio = 5 THEN P330_VNominal END) AS NominalR_5,
           MAX(CASE WHEN P330_premio = 5 THEN P330_Detalle  END) AS DetalleR_5
    FROM PlanSQL330 
    WHERE PLAN_Nro = 1234 
    AND   P330_premio IN( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
)
UPDATE td 
SET NominalR_1 = ps.NominalR_1,
    DetalleR_1 = ps.DetalleR_1,
    NominalR_2 = ps.NominalR_2,
    DetalleR_2 = ps.DetalleR_2,
    NominalR_3 = ps.NominalR_3,
    DetalleR_3 = ps.DetalleR_3,
    NominalR_4 = ps.NominalR_4,
    DetalleR_4 = ps.DetalleR_4,
    NominalR_5 = ps.NominalR_5,
    DetalleR_5 = ps.DetalleR_5
FROM #tabla_diseno2023v1 td
CROSS JOIN ctePlanSQL330_Pivot ps;
```

Sin embargo, al hacer esto necesitas tener la fila en existencia en tu tabla temporal. Al no haber ninguna columna que indique que vayas a tener otra fila, es probable que necesites un `INSERT` o simplemente generes el resultado como tal.

Aunque lo que me parece más lógico es que tengas múltiples líneas que puedan ser definidas por el número de plan. Así quedaría el ejemplo.

```
CREATE TABLE #tabla_diseno2023v1(
    PLAN_Nro   INT,
    NominalR_1 FLOAT NULL, 
    DetalleR_1 NVARCHAR(150) NULL,
    NominalR_2 FLOAT NULL, 
    DetalleR_2 NVARCHAR(150) NULL,
    NominalR_3 FLOAT NULL, 
    DetalleR_3 NVARCHAR(150) NULL,
    NominalR_4 FLOAT NULL, 
    DetalleR_4 NVARCHAR(150) NULL,
    NominalR_5 FLOAT NULL,
    DetalleR_5 NVARCHAR(150) NULL
);

WITH ctePlanSQL330_Pivot AS(
    SELECT PLAN_Nro,
           MAX(CASE WHEN P330_premio = 1 THEN P330_VNominal END) AS NominalR_1,
           MAX(CASE WHEN P330_premio = 1 THEN P330_Detalle  END) AS DetalleR_1,
           MAX(CASE WHEN P330_premio = 2 THEN P330_VNominal END) AS NominalR_2,
           MAX(CASE WHEN P330_premio = 2 THEN P330_Detalle  END) AS DetalleR_2,
           MAX(CASE WHEN P330_premio = 3 THEN P330_VNominal END) AS NominalR_3,
           MAX(CASE WHEN P330_premio = 3 THEN P330_Detalle  END) AS DetalleR_3,
           MAX(CASE WHEN P330_premio = 4 THEN P330_VNominal END) AS NominalR_4,
           MAX(CASE WHEN P330_premio = 4 THEN P330_Detalle  END) AS DetalleR_4,
           MAX(CASE WHEN P330_premio = 5 THEN P330_VNominal END) AS NominalR_5,
           MAX(CASE WHEN P330_premio = 5 THEN P330_Detalle  END) AS DetalleR_5
    FROM  PlanSQL330 
    WHERE P330_premio IN( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    GROUP BY PLAN_Nro
)
UPDATE td 
SET NominalR_1 = ps.NominalR_1,
    DetalleR_1 = ps.DetalleR_1,
    NominalR_2 = ps.NominalR_2,
    DetalleR_2 = ps.DetalleR_2,
    NominalR_3 = ps.NominalR_3,
    DetalleR_3 = ps.DetalleR_3,
    NominalR_4 = ps.NominalR_4,
    DetalleR_4 = ps.DetalleR_4,
    NominalR_5 = ps.NominalR_5,
    DetalleR_5 = ps.DetalleR_5
FROM #tabla_diseno2023v1 td
JOIN ctePlanSQL330_Pivot ps ON td.PLAN_Nro = ps.PLAN_Nro;
```

Comment: Me sirve mucho tu respuesta, gracias!